# Get unique name from a list of names

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of names

```
names = [
         "bob john", 
         "billy james",
         "bob joe",
         "bob joe henry",
         "bob", 
         "bob john martin", 
         "billy james phillip",
         "billy james phillip mark"
]
```

How can I return a list of all the full names? i.e.

```
full_names = [
              "bob joe henry",
              "bob john martin", 
              "billy James phillip mark" 
]
```

Would using a trie be appropriate in this scenario?

Comment: What is your definition of a full name? Anyone with three words?

Comment: What about `"bob henry"`? And just `"henry"`?

Comment: @MechanicPig thats the thing, Im given a list of arbitrary names, the first problem is finding the definition of a full name, my initial idea was to use some sort of edit distance to which I retain the largest values. Which leads to the second problem, defining a threshold if it even makes sense to

Comment: @lefe A full name could be of one, two or three words. It is as per your requirements what you consider as full name. However looking at your output it seems a three words name is considered as full name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  based on the output it looks like they are asking for you to remove the entries where the names are the beginnings of another name.  If you look at the full_names list, it is absent any names that had only the first portion of a name already in the list.

This short script will give you the same output as you requsted

```py
names = [
         "bob john",
         "billy james",
         "bob joe",
         "bob joe henry",
         "bob",
         "bob john martin",
         "billy james phillip"
]

end = len(names) - 1

while end >= 0:
    name = names[end]
    for i,x in enumerate(names):
        if i != end and name in x:
            del names[end]
            break
    end -= 1

print(names)
```

These next couple of lines do the same thing but more efficiently.  Thanks @stef for the suggestion.

```py
namesrt = sorted(names)
full_names = [namesrt[i] for i in range(len(namesrt) - 1) if not namesrt[i+1].startswith(namesrt[i])] + [namesrt[-1]]
```

Comment: You have a loop nested within another loop. This looks relatively inefficient. If you just sort the list of names first, then prefixes will always be located before the longer name, and you only have to compare a name with the next name.

Comment: @stef  great suggestion.  I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your definition of the full name is three words you can simply split the name by a space and check for the length

ex -

```
full_names = [n for n in names if len(n.split(" ")) == 3]
```

But if you want to really find full names across a big list. You need to find a big list of last names and first names. then check them against your name list.

Or you can train a spacy model using a name list and use it to identify first and last names. https://spacy.io/